# Does MATLAB execute basic array operations in constant space?

Tags: matlab, memory

I am getting an out of memory error on this line of MATLAB code:

```
result = (A(1:xmax,1:ymax,1:zmax) .* B(2:xmax+1,2:ymax+1,2:zmax+1) +
         A(2:xmax+1,2:ymax+1,2:zmax+1) .* B(1:xmax,1:ymax,1:zmax)) ./ C
```

where C is another array. This is on 32 bit MATLAB (I can't seem to get the 64 bit version at the moment, which would temporarily fix my problems).

The arrays result, A, B, and C are pre-initialized and never change size. It is then my guess that this computation is not being performed in constant space.

Is this correct? Is there a way to make it run or check if it is running in constant space?

These arrays of are approximate size (250, 250, 250).

If MATLAB does not run this in constant size, does anyone have any experience as to whether Octave or Julia or (insert similar language) does?

**edit 1:**

I eliminated excess arrays. There are 10 arrays that are 258 x 258 x 338, which corresponds to 1.67 GB. There are a bunch of other variables but they are much smaller. The calculation presented is simplified, the form of the calculation is:

```
R = (A(3Drange) .* B(3Drange) + A(new_3Drange) .* D(new_3Drange) + . . . ) ./ C
```

where the ranges generally just differ by a shift of plus or minus 1 or 2.

The output of memory command:

```
Maximum possible array:    669 MB (7.013e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   1541 MB (1.616e+09 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:   2209 MB (2.316e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   8154 MB (8.550e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.
```

Apparently I should be violating the second line. However, the code runs fine until the first operation that I actually do with the arrays. Perhaps MATLAB is being lazy and not allocating when I type:

```
A=zeros(xmax+2,ymax+2,zmax+2);
```

but still telling me in the workspace that the variable is allocated.

This code has worked before with smaller arrays. (edit: but it seems the actual memory size is the problem, not the size of each individual array).

The very curious thing to me is why it does not error during allocation, but instead errors during the first calculation.

**edit 2:**

I have confirmed that the loop is not running constant in space. There is about a .8 GB of memory being allocated during the calculation. Here is an image of resource usage while the command is being executed in a loop:
[image: CPU usage during the loop]
However, I tried breaking up the computation into multiple lines. I split the computation at each addition and added on each part in a new command, treating `R` as a accumulator. The result is that less memory is allocated at one time, but presumably more often. Here is the picture: [image: CPU usage during the new loop]

I am still curious as to why MATLAB doesn't want to execute this in constant space. I think it perhaps has something to do with the indexing being shifted - I am planning on investigating it more later and then putting this all together in an answer, but someone may beat me to it, which would be great also. Now, though, I can run the array size I was looking for and can finish my project.

Comment: What makes you think that it's not running in constant space?

Comment: See if you can pre-allocate `result`.  That will at least see if everything fits.

Comment: try allocating your repetitive variables such as `1:xmax`, `a=1:xmax`, `A(a,b,c).*B(a+1,b+1,c+1) + A(a+1,b+1,c+1) .*B(a,b,c))./C`

Comment: A 250x250x250 array of `double` should only be around 125MB. Three of them is 375MB; including the space for one temporary and one result increases this to 625MB. That should be easy to handle for MATLAB, unless you've got a whole bunch of other arrays. Try running the calculation when those three arrays are the only variables in the workspace.

Comment: I think it is not constant space because MATLAB is okay up until that statement. Everything has been pre-allocated (including result) and is visible in the workspace. That statement errors. It is a subset of what the actual code is (the actual code has more arrays being added in similar manners before the ./ C).

Comment: Why does it not execute it constant space? Because memory allocation speed is fast, and they don't design around people still using old 32-bit computers/OSes/versions anymore. These days, for many of the things that Matlab does, using memory is almost always faster than using the CPU. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space–time_tradeoff).

Comment: @horchler But I find it hard to believe that something that I can write a very, very fast constant space loop for in C, multithreaded too, would be slower if it did not allocate .8 GB in extra space. This may very well be what is happening though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that most of the question has already been answered:

### Does it operate in constant space?

No as you verified, it does not.

### Why doesn't it operate in constant space?

Matlab claims to be fast at vectorized matrix operations, not so much emphasis is placed on memory efficiency.

### What to do now?

Here are different options, the first one is preferred if possible, the other two are certainly possible.

1. Make it fit, for example by upgrading to 64 bit matlab or by not putting other stuf in your workspace
2. Work on parts of the matrix, so for example cut it in half
3. Dont use vectorization at all but make a simple for loop

If you don't vectorize, you will have a minimal space solution.